# JSON Webscraper returning empty array

Tags: json, parsing

Im trying to parse a website using the following code:

```
    import requests 
    r = requests.get('https://www.finn.no/realestate/homes/search.html?sort=PUBLISHED_DESC')
    print(r.json())
```

However, it appears that it just returns an empty array.

I tried putting it in a dict and catching the response using

```
 import sys, json

struct = {}
try:
    dataform = str(r).strip("'<>() ").replace('\'', '\"')
    struct = json.loads(dataform)
except:
    print(repr(r))
    print(sys.exc_info())
    
struct
```

And the code returns:

<Response [200]>
(<class 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError'>, JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)') ....

Answer (score 0):

Now you're trying to treat HTML document as Json, so obviously thats not what you want. The page's Json data is embedded inside one `<script>` element so you can use `beautifulsoup` to locate it and `json` module to parse it:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.finn.no/realestate/homes/search.html?sort=PUBLISHED_DESC"
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

data = soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__")
data = json.loads(data.text)

# pretty print the data:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "props": {
        "pageProps": {
            "search": {
                "docs": [
                    {
                        "type": "realestate",
                        "ad_id": 276867609,
                        "main_search_key": "SEARCH_ID_REALESTATE_NEWBUILDINGS",
                        "heading": "Unik anledning! \u00d8nsker du \u00e5 bo med \"leilighetsf\u00f8lelse\" rett ved bysentrum, og likevel ha plass til storfamilien?",
                        "location": "Fauchaldsgate 2, Gj\u00f8vik",
                        "image": {
                            "url": "https://images.finncdn.no/dynamic/default/2022/11/vertical-0/22/9/276/867/609_1157963344.jpg",
                            "path": "2022/11/vertical-0/22/9/276/867/609_1157963344.jpg",
                            "height": 1280,
                            "width": 1920,
                            "aspect_ratio": 1.5
                        },

...and so on.
```